# CefSharp - How to get feedback if clicked an inputfield?

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm new to CefSharp. Right now on **one side** I'm using cefsharp on my **server** to get an image/screenshot of my off-screen-browser. On the **other side** I have the **client** that is requesting and interacting with this image.

So clicking on the image, getting the coordinates and transfer that information to cefsharp to perform the same interaction, works well. But now I'm sitting in front of an login-screen and want to click the inputfield.
So clicking works, but now **I want to spawn a keyboard, so I can type sth into the inputfield**. **How can I get feedback that I clicked into an inputfield?**

My project is setup in Unity, C#.

Comment: The `WPF` version of `CefSharp` doesn't support on screen keyboards, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1736

Comment: does that mean it wont show up a keyboard? If yes, thats not what I want. I need just feedback that I'm in a inputfield, so I can instantiate my keyboard.

Comment: If you just need a notification then that's different, http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRenderProcessMessageHandler_OnFocusedNodeChanged.htm http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_FocusedNodeChangedEnabled.htm make sure you enable it before calling `Cef.Initialize` or creating any browser instances.

Comment: See has just added a new api for onscreen keyboard notifications see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2607/virtual-keyboard-support-in-off-screen it'll still need to be added to the CefSharp api